# Where are PHP model classes defined for use?

Tags: php

I was wondering where functions and classes are defined for php...

I remember looking at WordPress source, and they were calling functions without including files, so I'm curious where this stuff is defined.

What I'm looking at doing putting some connection code, like mysql or like for twilio below

```
  require "sms/Twilio.php";
  $AccountSid = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
  $AuthToken = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

I'm then thinking of putting just this in a file and including it in many places, but I'm curious if it can get easier than including a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using PHP5, it's best to use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

It allows you to assign multiple autoloader methods/functions, but otherwise works in much the same way as `__autoload()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use __autoload

See http://www.php.net/__autoload